# Column valorize with ,00 in Sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with a column in Oracle Db, the column is valorize with ,00 and it refers at decimal numbers, i don't can modify the column, but in the query this column must be valorize like 0,00.
Anyone can help me!! Thank you very much!

The example of column:

[image: the example of column ,00]

Comment: Please provide your sample data and expected result

Comment: What is the datatype of the `valorize` column?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, it is about `TO_CHAR` function and appropriate format mask you'd want to use. Here are several examples:

```
SQL> with test (valorize) as
  2    (select 0     from dual union all
  3     select 10    from dual union all
  4     select 5.2   from dual union all
  5     select 0.1   from dual union all
  6     select 2.25  from dual
  7    )
  8  select valorize,
  9         to_char(valorize, '999D99') res1,
 10         to_char(valorize, '000D00') res2,
 11         to_char(valorize, '990D00') res3,
 12         to_char(valorize, 'fm990D00') res3
 13  from test;

  VALORIZE RES1    RES2    RES3    RES3
---------- ------- ------- ------- -------
         0     ,00  000,00    0,00 0,00
        10   10,00  010,00   10,00 10,00
       5,2    5,20  005,20    5,20 5,20
        ,1     ,10  000,10    0,10 0,10
      2,25    2,25  002,25    2,25 2,25

SQL>
```

More [format models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210); have a look.

Comment: yes, now work thank you very much, the example is very clear